# square brackets in tcl arrays

Tags: arrays, tcl, square-bracket

I have the following problem:

```
set start "input[0]"
set end   "output[0]"
set myArray($start,$end,pin) 1
set x "input[0]"
set y "output[0]"
set test [array names myArray $x,$y,pin]
puts "\n$test"
```

output should be:

```
input[0],output[0]
```

but output is:

```
{}
```

if I do:

```
set test [array names myArray *,*,pin]
puts "\n$test"
```

output is:

```
input[0],output[0]
```

Also, if I replace `[]` by `{}` `ie.input{0},output{0}`
original code works.

Can someone please tell me what is happening here? How do I escape the `[]` brackets?

Answer (score 3):

Well, let's look what is going on here:

```
set start "input[0]"
```

This will execute the command `0`. I don't know what that does, but you propably don't want that. Either escape brackets with `\` or use `{}` to enclose the name.

Same applies for

```
set end   "output[0]"
# ...
set x "input[0]"
set y "output[0]"
```

But it doesn't look like you have that problem.

The next thing is that you pass a glob pattern to `array names`:

```
set test [array names myArray $x,$y,pin]
```

Tcl uses `[]` in glob patterns for character choices, simmilar to regexp. So your pattern will only match `input0,output0,pin`. You can avoid that by passing the `-exact` switch to `array names`:

```
set test [array names myArray -exact $x,$y,pin]
```

Or you can escape the brackets again with a backslash (note that the pattern should look like `input\[0\],input\[1\],pin` *after* Tcl did all kinds of substitution.)

Comment: This works for the case mention above.

I have another case where I cannot use -exact:

`set test [array names myArray $x,$y,*,length]`

The -exact option fails for obvious reasons here. I'm not able to work around the square brackets in $x and $y and the * using -regexp. Any idea about what is going on here ?

Comment: @user3119236 Why are you using `array names` at all? It seems to me like you're doing something the wrong way, and that you need to take a step back and think what you're trying to do overall. Perhaps putting a dictionary inside an array element would be more suitable, or maybe mapping things as some sort of object?

Comment: Us string map to precede all square bracket occurrences by slash:
    set checkname [string map {\[ \\\[ \] \\\]} "$x,$y,*,length"]
    set test [array names myArray $checkname]